# Why is most of the output not being redirected to the file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that opens a PS session as bypass policy and executes whatever the PS script needs to execute

```
set "psFile=.\main.ps1"

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "&{%psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 | Tee-Object -FilePath log.txt}"
```

I am getting what I want: output to both console AND file. however, when I opened the file after the execution was finished, it only contained like one line from everything else that was printed on the console. 99% of the output was not redirected to the log file.

Why is that?

Also, one more thing, I would like to use this bat file for any PS script, so I tried doing something like this:

```
set psFile="%1"

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "&{%psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 | Tee-Object -FilePath log.txt}"
```

and when i open a CMD and type the following:

```
runPS.bat main.ps1 DB1
```

it complains:

> The term 'main.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>       operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>       again.

Comment: The leading ``.\`` is as important in Powershell as it is in Bash. Without, you are not accessing the file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get fullpath of 1st argument.
for %%A in ("%~1") do set "psfile=%%~fA"

rem Save log in same directory of 1st argument.
set "logfile=%~dp1log.txt"

if defined psfile (
    rem Run the PS1 file with remaining arguments and tee the piped stdout stream.
    Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "&{&'%psFile%' '%~2' '%~3' '%~4' '%~5' '%~6' | Tee-Object -FilePath '%logfile%'}"
)
```

The `for` loop will get the full path of the 1st argument
if a fullpath was not passed.

The log file is recommended as a fullpath, to insure success,
and the knowing where it is saved.

The single quotes surrrounding the paths helps with any
possible whitespace etc.

Tested with PS1 to show passed arguments:

```
$args
```

which seems to show all stdout OK with a test.

To include other streams, view [About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: ok i think its at least recognizing the ps file, however, the %~2 argument is not accepting param input to the ps script. its giving me error: the PS script is supposed to prompt me for input (which would be passed to the %2 arg, but instead its erroring out. if i try to pass it on the command as such: runPS.bat main.ps1 DB1 ....it complains: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument.) if i dont pass the argument (i.e. DB1) it complians: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DB_input' because it is
an empty string.

Comment: Many of the errors seem to be from the PS code. Not that the PS code is incorrect, but rather the set rules of argument handling is not compatible between the sender (*batch-file*) and the receiver (*PS*). I could perhaps help further if a minimal PS code with the PS Params section and the input that is causing you problems. It might work better if the batch-file arguments passed are appended to a variable before passing to the PS script, so that `''` arguments are not passed. That is a guess and without knowing and testing what the PS requires, I could guess incorrect.